# PHP-behaviour: Why is code in PHP-tags not displayed on screen?

Tags: php

What is the reason for the PHP-behaviour described in the code-snippet?

```
// "demo.txt" is a plain text file.
// Content is read into a string.
$demo = file_get_contents('http://example.com/demo.txt'); 
// Browser displays the content of the text-file.
echo $demo;

// "functions.php" is a php-file.
// Read into a string.
$demo = file_get_contents('http://example.com/functions.php');
// Browser displays nothing. 
echo $demo;
```

Comment: When asking questions, please provide a specific example of what you're trying to achieve and also what you've currently done.To learn more about asking great questions, see How to Ask- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: When you request a PHP file via HTTP, it is normally parsed by the server, so the only output you will get is the output the PHP script generates – if any. If it doesn’t generate any output, you will get no utput accordingly. (Think about it, if that wasn’t the case, then anyone could read the database passwords etc. you might have stored in variables in your PHP files.)

Comment: Maybe try setting a plain text header in the functions.php file.

Comment: Great explanation.
I have understood it now. 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$demo = file_get_contents('http://example.com/functions.php');
echo $demo;
```

`$demo` contains whatever the link returns. "http://example.com/functions.php" is a php file and it is not given any output, which means it does not output anything during execution. So you are not getting a visible result.

For more understanding, put `echo "Hello world";` in your `function.ph`p file and then execute. You will get "Hello world" as content.

Comment: You have helped me a lot understanding the issue. Thanks.